# fetch entities with missing or null property?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying for entities with missing properties in app engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332080/querying-for-entities-with-missing-properties-in-app-engine-datastore)

I'm using Objectify4, 
If a field is not set, from the datastore viewer we can see it is marked as `<missing>` or `<null>`, Is there a way to fetch these entities?

Comment: No, there is no way. You can specify a default value for this property and then query for it. Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332080/querying-for-entities-with-missing-properties-in-app-engine-datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make queries for properties that are missing or not set for an Entity. However, you can query for properties that were initialized with `null` value. For more information take a look [Restrictions on Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries).

Hope this helps!