# Datastore: `SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE property IS NULL` returns no result despite entities without property

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql, gqlquery

I am using Google Cloud Datastore and successfully stored entities.

Now I am trying to query them based on the presence of a property.
I use the "Query by GQL" tab in the Datastore UI: https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql

For some entities, I did not specify the `property` property when I saved them, so I expect these to be set to  `NULL`.
However, when I query `SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE property IS NULL`, no result is returned.

Answer (score 3):

This is working as intended:

According to the [Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#tips_about_gql_behavior):

> **Null is a value, not the absence of a value.**
>   There is no way to determine whether an entity lacks a value for a property (that is, whether the property has no value). If you use a condition of the form `nonexistent = NULL`, what will occur is a check whether a null value is explicitly stored for that property. For example, `SELECT * FROM Task WHERE nonexistent = NULL` will never yield an entity with no value set for property `nonexistent`.

So to explicitly retrieve entities with `property` set to `NULL`, you would have to store the `property: NULL` for these entities.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. NULL is not the same as property not present.

But as mentioned by Nick Johnson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332080/querying-for-entities-with-missing-properties-in-app-engine-datastore#comment3459398_3332120),

> The workaround would be to provide a default value for the updated property, and query for that value

I haven't tried this personally, and I am not sure if it works, but I suggest you to try this.

If it doesn't work, the only other option is to go through every record of the model and update all the existing entities which do not have a value, with a default value.