# Is there a way to filter entities that that have missing property in a gcloud datastore python api?

Tags: python, gcloud, datastore, add-filter

I am trying to run a query, that will return only entities that have a missing property.

I have tried this:

```py
query = client.query(kind='IPs')
query.add_filter('property_name','=',None)
```

But this returns an empty dataset.

Is there any way to do this without inventing another property?

> Note: I am using google-cloud-datstore library with python3.6

Answer (score 0):

No. A case of you don't know what you don't know :-(

Though note there's a difference between an entity not having a property and having the property with a default value.

If an entity does not include the property, the entity is not part of the property's index and thus inaccessible from it.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332120/609290

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems that the solution is providing a default value for a property. Will research this and update.